# Mule4 using read connector to read a file

Tags: mule, mule-esb

I am very new to Mule4 and using it for the first time. I am trying to move a file from one directory to another. I have a "Read file" connector and "Write file" connector. In the Read connector, I specified the file path and the working directory. on the Write connector, I also specified the working directory and the path. However, the file is not moved from the source to target directory. But if I add an HTTP listener at the beginning of the flow, then it will work if I access it through http://localhost:8081. But I want to know how can I accomplish this whenever there is a new file in the source, so the flow automatically moves the file from source to target directory?  Please see the screenshot

[image: This Flow doesn't work]

[image: This flow works]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need something to trigger the flow to run. `file:read` doesn’t do this automatically that’s why http requests to trigger works for you.

All flows need a ‘Source’ to trigger them unless you are calling them from other flows using `flow-ref` (or from dataweave using a lookup()).

If you know the exact file you want then you can put a scheduler before your `file:read` to trigger the flow:

```
<scheduler>
  <scheduling-strategy>
    <fixed-frequency startDelay="5" frequency="10" timeUnit="SECONDS"/>
  </scheduling-strategy>
</scheduler>
```

Or you can use a file:listener to listen for new files in a directory etc as the source directly:

```
<flow name="onNewFile">
  <file:listener config-ref="file" directory="test-data/in" autoDelete="true">
    <scheduling-strategy>
      <fixed-frequency frequency="1000"/>
    </scheduling-strategy>
  </file:listener>
  ...
</flow>
```

You can use fixed frequency or cron. More details here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/scheduler-xml-reference